# Type '{ file: ArrayBuffer; url: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ file: Blob; url: string; }'

Tags: angular, typescript

The method below produces this error.
Can it be fixed without changing the return type of the method.
Is there any cast I can do to resolve the error?

```
private downloadIt(url: string, applicationData: any, getRequest?: boolean): Observable<{ file: Blob, url: string }> {        
    return this.http.get(url, applicationData, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
        map(file => {
            const url = this.window.window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            return { file, url };
        })
    );
```

Comment: `return { new Blob([file]), url };`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
private downloadIt(url: string, applicationData: any, getRequest?: boolean): Observable<{ file: Blob, url: string }> {        
    return this.http.get(url, applicationData, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
        map(file => {
            const url = this.window.window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            const blobFile = new Blob([new Uint8Array(file)]);
            return { file: blobFile, url };
        })
    );
```